# PHP - Fail to include other file

Tags: php

I have problem with including values from other file in php.
I have **2** files, **cfg.php** and **file.php**. **cfg.php** return array and **file.php** takes values from **cfg.php** (config file).

**cfg.php**

```
<?php
return array(
    'test' => 'localhost',
    'test2' => 'localhost'
);
?>
```

**file.php**

```
<?php
$cfg = include('cfg.php');

var_dump($cfg);
?>
```

Result from **file.php**: ﻿int(1)
If i try to get a value like: *$cfg['test']*, result is NULL, why?

Where is error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Include just loads the other script in front of this one. You can't catch it in a variable.

What you can do is use a function.

```
<?php
function config() {
  return array(
    'test' => 'localhost',
    'test2' => 'localhost'
  );
}
?>
```

And then

```
<?php
include('cfg.php');
$cfg = config();

var_dump($cfg);
?>
```

The `1` you were initially getting is to indicate that the include was succesfull, you caught the status of the include function rather then it's content.

Update:
Thinking of it, you can also set the config variable in the cfg file like this:

```
<?php
 $cfg = array(
    'test' => 'localhost',
    'test2' => 'localhost'
  );
?>
```

After include the variable will be available in the other page.

Comment: Your solution works with added **__DIR__** before cfg.php. Thank you!

Comment: This is what i mean. Finally problem: dont added **__DIR__**.  Thanks for your help.